# H2 Memory Database: Unselectable Data

Tags: java, h2

I've been using a persistent data store for nearly a year now, connecting with the string

`jdbc:h2:gpfp;MV_STORE=FALSE;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=0;FILE_LOCK=NO`

and running unit tests; all has been good and well.  Recently, I decided to try the complete in-memory mode instead of just using memory tables.  I connected to my database using the H2 console and executed

`SCRIPT TO 'c:\temp\mpfp.db'`

to generate a backup that I would load to an in-memory database using.

`RUNSCRIPT FROM 'c:\temp\mpfp.db'`

This appears to work well in-that I generate an in-memory database with the tables and content I need; I tested this both in the console and through my application.  However, when I run my unit tests I noticed a single test now fails (the 15th out of 19 to be exact)...  I'm executing a simple select on a column and the db engine is unable to retrieve the results, but if I select the entire dataset and scroll through I can find the value.  I've confirm this to NOT be a case-sensitivity issue in my manual testing.

What's happening here?  I checked the data in the database and in the generated file from SCRIPT TO.  I haven't changed any of my unit tests just the database composition; memory vs persistent.

It may help to know that the DDL that generates the original tables uses CREATE MEMORY TABLE for each table and I'm using H2 version 1.4.178...  Could this be a problem with MV_STORE?  I explicitly set it to false in the persistent store because I was having a similar problem where I wasn't getting results, but appending MV_STORE=FALSE to the jdbc:h2:mem:... didn't seem to do anything.  I also bumped the JVM memory to 2g and 4g as another test and the outcome is still the same.

Comment: I reverted the h2 dependency back to version 1.3.176 and this doesn't seem to be a problem.  Anyone else have similar development issues?